# LPM implementation for linux kernel module

Tags: linux, algorithm, kernel, kernel-module

I want to implement Longest Prefix Match algorithm in kernel module by using data structures provided by linux kernel (like hlist, prio_tree, radix tree etc).
Which data structure of linux kernel best suits for implementing LPM? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For IP addresses matching, Linux Kernel uses LC-tries(prefix tree) data structure and algorithm.

I think your Longest Prefix Matching implementation can be based on the LC-tries.

The source codes are in ./net/ipv4/fib_trie.c

Comment: Thanks tian for your prompt answer.

Comment: Thanks tian for your prompt answer.
I am actually trying to build a kernel module which will save routing entries in his own table. As I am currently in process of searching, I came across the FIB in "./include/net/ip_fib.h". Does it serve the purpose? My only confusion is that does the FIB API provides you a table completely independant of linux tables?
Thanks for your help.